# No response while retrieving image from server

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am uploading image and retrieving the response from my server. Following is my php code

```
<?php

    //Constants for database connection
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASS','root');
    define('DB_NAME','simplifiedcoding');

    //We will upload files to this folder
    //So one thing don't forget, also create a folder named uploads inside your project folder i.e. MyApi folder
    define('UPLOAD_PATH', 'uploads/');

    //connecting to database
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to connect');


    //An array to display the response
    $response = array();

    //if the call is an api call
    if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

        //switching the api call
        switch($_GET['apicall']){

            //if it is an upload call we will upload the image
            case 'uploadpic':

                //first confirming that we have the image and tags in the request parameter
        if(isset($_FILES['pic']['name']) && isset($_POST['tags'])){

                    //uploading file and storing it to database as well
                    try{
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_PATH . $_FILES['pic']['name']);
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image, tags) VALUES (?,?)");
                        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_FILES['pic']['name'],$_POST['tags']);
                        if($stmt->execute()){
                            $response['error'] = false;
                            $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully';
                        }else{
                            throw new Exception("Could not upload file");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception $e){
                        $response['error'] = true;
                        $response['message'] = 'Could not upload file';
                    }

                }else{
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "Required params not available";
                }

            break;

            //in this call we will fetch all the images
            case 'getpics':

                //getting server ip for building image url
                $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

                //query to get images from database
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, image, tags FROM images");
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $image, $tags);

                $images = array();

                //fetching all the images from database
                //and pushing it to array
                while($stmt->fetch()){
                    $temp = array();
                    $temp['id'] = $id;
                    $temp['image'] = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/MyApi/'. UPLOAD_PATH . $image;
                    $temp['tags'] = $tags;

                    array_push($images, $temp);
                }

                //pushing the array in response
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['images'] = $images;
            break;

            default:
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid api call';
        }

    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        echo "<h1>404 Not Found</h1>";
        echo "The page that you have requested could not be found.";
        exit();
    }

    //displaying the response in json
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
  ?>
```

I am able to successfully upload the image and see the entry in mysql server. I tried with postman and i am getting correct response while retrieving image but when i click button in my android application to retrieve response of uploaded images, i am getting nothing.
Foll is my Android code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //ImageView to display image selected
    ImageView imageView, imageView2;

    //edittext for getting the tags input
    EditText editTextTags;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing views
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        editTextTags = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTags);
        imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.image2);

        //checking the permission
        //if the permission is not given we will open setting to add permission
        //else app will not open
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }


        //adding click listener to button
        findViewById(R.id.buttonUploadImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //if the tags edittext is empty
                //we will throw input error
                if (editTextTags.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    editTextTags.setError("Enter tags first");
                    editTextTags.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                //if everything is ok we will open image chooser
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.retrieveimage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "yy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,EndPoints.GET_PICS_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                            Log.i("Abbu", "onResponse: "+response.toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            //    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(stringRequest);
                MySingleton.getMySingleton(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            //getting the image Uri
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                //getting bitmap object from uri
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                //displaying selected image to imageview
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                //calling the method uploadBitmap to upload image
                uploadBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * The method is taking Bitmap as an argument
    * then it will return the byte[] array for the given bitmap
    * and we will send this array to the server
    * here we are using PNG Compression with 80% quality
    * you can give quality between 0 to 100
    * 0 means worse quality
    * 100 means best quality
    * */
    public byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    private void uploadBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap) {

        //getting the tag from the edittext
        final String tags = editTextTags.getText().toString().trim();

        //our custom volley request
        VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                            Log.i("abu", "onResponse: " + obj);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {

            /*
            * If you want to add more parameters with the image
            * you can do it here
            * here we have only one parameter with the image
            * which is tags
            * */
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("tags", tags);
                return params;
            }

            /*
            * Here we are passing image by renaming it with a unique name
            * */
            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                long imagename = System.currentTimeMillis();
                params.put("pic", new DataPart(imagename + ".png", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap)));
                return params;
            }
        };

        //adding the request to volley
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(volleyMultipartRequest);
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when i click my retrieve button.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the request hitting the webserver? (In the webserver logs)

Comment: When i do with postman{
    "error": false,
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "image": "http://Priitshs-MacBook-Air.local/MyApi/uploads/1512134002081.png",
            "tags": "uu"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "image": "http://Priitshs-MacBook-Air.local/MyApi/uploads/1512134056482.png",
            "tags": "qq"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "image": "http://Priitshs-MacBook-Air.local/MyApi/uploads/lakebell.jpg",
            "tags": "pppppp"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: With Android... If you don't see it then check the part of your application where you add the request to volley's queue. See if that is working as should. Also see if in Android monitor you have any related errors. Or any try cath without logging the exception...

Comment: i am not getting any error in logcat

Comment: Have you checked if this works ok: MySingleton.getMySingleton(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);